# How to control task create maxConcurrentOperationCount

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

```
 - (NSURLSession *)session{
        if (!_session) {
            NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

            _session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

        }
        return _session;
    }


-(void)start {
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.2.7:8080/Music/movie.mp4"];
            self.task =   [self.session downloadTaskWithURL:url];
            [self.task resume];
    }

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location{
    NSString *filePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:downloadTask.response.suggestedFilename];
    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    [fm moveItemAtURL:location toURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath] error:nil];
}
```

When I [self start] take up a lot of memory and create a lot of theard

[image]
[image]
How to use less memory by control less theard?

Comment: How big is `movie.mp4`?

Comment: movie.mp4 is 860MB,I think movie is download in TMP file,is not in memory,maybe I wrong?but memory It does not become a lot by sometime

Comment: Threads aren't a big issue.  Have you used the memory instrument to look at what is using memory?

Comment: I Unskilled use instrument,I see not one use a lot of memory

Comment: Are you just starting 1 download? Is this running on a device or in the simulator?

Comment: just starting 1download,that is running on a simulator,Being not happen on a device

Comment: You know that your question is mistagged as NSURLDownload (a very outdated API that's only available on OS X), right?  Anyway, the short answer is to change the session configuration to limit the number of simultaneous connections, and perhaps to periodically invalidate your session and recreate it.  But I don't see any reason why you think the network communications are the cause of your memory usage.  Is this in the simulator, by chance?  If so, Instruments is probably lying to you.